# managing APNS and FCM tokens on server

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to figure out how to manage APNS tokens on a device registration and push notification server I'm writing.

The crux of the problem has to do with uniquely identifying the device across uninstalls and app updates. Even the identifier for vendor can change across installs or updates. It seems as though Apple and Google don't really want you to be able to do this.

There appear to be some workarounds such as using the keychain on iOS devices and internal storage on Android, but from what I understand at least one of these methods requires a user permission which can turn away some users. I want to respect my users' privacy and build trust with them.

Here is the logic I've come up with so far:

1. store push tokens which will be uniquely identified by `application Id`, `platform`, `user Id` and `device Id` (unique value stored by app in localstorage) - we'll call this unique identifier the `APUD Id`
2. we'll have what is essentially an upsert endpoint (as much as I generally hate upserts or really any generic endpoint - it seems this might be a good case for an exception) which takes an update to the token or other device data and determines if there's an existing matching `APUD Id` - if so update that row otherwise create a new one
3. When sending push notifications to a particular user's device find all matching entries that have not yet been soft deleted (maybe a hard delete is easier here to avoid concurrency errors when multiple service instances are involved, but that is OT - ideally we are persisting this data at least for some period of time for support and debugging purposes). Since we can not uniquely identify a device these notifications should use the appropriate collapse id (which should allow the device to uniquely identify a notification) to prevent a user from receiving duplicate notifications.
4. If Apple or Google respond with an indication that the token has expired/unregistered then soft delete the entry.

Questions:

1. Is step 4 reliable? Is there a better way to do this? Is there some way to pro-actively manage expired tokens through a cron job? Will this just result in a massive build-up of tokens that rarely expire?
2. Is there generally a better or even canonical way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic looks good. It's similar (if not identical) to the approach I've been suggesting in a few of my answers.

> Is step 4 reliable? Is there a better way to do this? Is there some way to pro-actively manage expired tokens through a cron job? Will this just result in a massive build-up of tokens that rarely expire?

It is reliable to the point that it should prevent the *build-up* of tokens and preventing unnecessary push requests.

> Is there generally a better or even canonical way to approach this?

I have yet to find a *better* approach to handle the FCM tokens other than this.

Depending on any other specs you have (or might soon have), just make sure to (as much as possible that:

- the token mapping for each user is accurate (through each platform's `onTokenRefresh()`)
- that expired tokens are deleted (or archived if needed e.g. debugging)